# How can I change the default icon for a file extension?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file, icons

I'd like to change a type of file's icon to a new one . so i add this snippet :

```
AF_FileAssociator assoc = new AF_FileAssociator(".akp");
       string icon = assoc.DefaultIcon.IconPath;
       ProgramIcon newDefIcon = new ProgramIcon(@"ake.ico");
       assoc.DefaultIcon = newDefIcon;
```

see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43675/C-FileAssociation-Class)

Even i put the absolute path of the icon like this for example:

```
ProgramIcon newDefIcon = new ProgramIcon(@"D:\ake.ico");
```

I get the same result.

I have the icon `ake.ico` in the root of my project . When i launch the program the string `icon` takes as value `ake.ico` .

The problem is that the files with the extension `.akp` still haven't icon .

- What is the reason of this problem?
- How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution : i set the icon path value equal to the path of executable application . and it's works

Answer (score 2):

set the file association with your executable in this way...

add these lines of code in your main class

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")]

public static void SHChangeNotify(int wEventId, int uFlags, int dwItem1, int dwItem2)
{
}
```

then in form load event add this code

```
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".glx").SetValue("", "Galaxy Database", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("Galaxy Database\\shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath + " \"%l\" ", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
const dynamic SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = 0x8000000;
const dynamic SHCNF_IDLIST = 0;
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0);
```

build your project and run the exe as Administartor. The icon of exe will be applied to the .apk files.

remarks: It requires administrative privileges to change some file associations. Comment the code and rebuild to disable the feature. Still the association will remain with your exe. Double clicking on *.apk file will open  it with your exe.